# Auth Mellon is not redirecting to IDP. Apache is returning 404 for /mellon

Tags: httpd, saml, okta

I am trying to enable auth mellon for on-prem weblogic app.

I have apache httpd and auth mellon installed on RHEL 6.8. I followed instructions as per https://github.com/Uninett/mod_auth_mellon/wiki/GenericSetup

My IDP is Okta.

Mellon.conf looks like this

```
    NameVirtualHost *:7799
    <VirtualHost *:7799>
    ServerName webapp.mycompany.com
    ProxyPass /mellon/ !
    <Location />
    MellonEnable info
    Require all granted
    MellonEndpointPath /mellon
    MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/httpd/mellon/mellon_metadata.xml
    MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/httpd/mellon/mellon_metadata.key
    MellonSPCertFile /etc/httpd/mellon/mellon_metadata.cert
    MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/httpd/mellon/idp_metadata.xml 
    </Location>

    <Location /wlsapp>
    AuthType Mellon
    MellonEnable auth
    Require valid-user
    ProxyPass http://12.13.14.15:7001/wlsapp/
    ProxyPassReverse http://12.13.14.15:7001/wlsapp/
    </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access webapp.mycompany.com/wlsapp I get "404 Not Found" **The requested URL /mellon/login was not found on this server.**
URL on browser is `https://webapp.mycompany.com/mellon/login?ReturnTo=http%3A%2F%webapp%2D.mycompany.com%2Fwlsapp&IdP=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.okta.com%2Fexkyqo99f4cxyzUp2h7`

Any suggestions? I dont understand why I am getting 404.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to rewrite rule that is redirecting the request to  another server. I had to control this redirection